# Docker can not resolve names when building images

Tags: docker, dns

This works:

```
$ docker run -it --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 debian ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.22.14): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.22.14: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=18.675 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.22.14: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=17.605 ms
```

This doesn't:

```
$ docker run -it debian ping google.com
ping: unknown host
```

So it seems I am having DNS issues (no idea why, this was working fine some time ago, and I haven't made any relevant changes to my Ubuntu 16.04 System).

Accordingly, building an image fails:

```
$ docker build -f Dockerfile -t testing .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 182.1 MB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:xenial
 ---> bd3d4369aebc
Step 2 : USER root
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f53149b7a4f2
Step 3 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y tree
 ---> Running in 1187db5f2a03
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
```

But I do not know how to specify dns settings while building an image:

```
$ docker build --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 -f Dockerfile -t testing .
flag provided but not defined: --dns
See 'docker build --help'.
```

What can I do to provide DNS settings to `docker build`?

(Ideally I would solve my DNS issues, but I do not think I can do that easily, and I need to move on at the moment)

Comment: Please show `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and `docker run --rm ubuntu:xenial cat /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @BMitch: thanks, but it seems the problem was a certain `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf`, with an entry to access the private registry in my corporate LAN. Some 2 months ago we installed our own registry, and I simply forgot about it. My bad.